# Initial color... how's it work?

Tags: css, background

I need to be able to set the background color of a div back to it's original state. I can store it in a variable and recall it, but was wondering why I can't use "initial". Is that now what it's for... to set a css property back to it's initial state?

Thanks in advance.

```js
testDiv.style.background = "red";

//Shouldn't this turn it back to it's original state of yellow?
testDiv.style.background = "initial";
```

```css
#testDiv{
  background-color: yellow;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial):

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial (or default) value of a
>   property to an element. It can be applied to any CSS property.

And

> The initial value of a CSS property is its default value, as listed in
>   its definition table.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value)</sup>

So unlike you think, initial will put the initial value **before** you set your `background-color` and it's not the value *you* set.

---

Since JS add inline style you can simply delete that style to get back to the yellow color without extra variable as your style remain defined but is simply overridden:

```js
testDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";

//empty the style attribute
testDiv.style="";
/*OR
testDiv.style.backgroundColor="";
*/
```

```css
#testDiv{
  background-color: yellow;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `initial` as the *value* of the `style.background` property of the element - that means that it will override whatever the default background color is from the CSS that selects the element. If you want to reset the `background` property to what's specified by the CSS, use `removeProperty` instead, to completely remove the property that was Javascript-set, so that the page's CSS regains the highest priority:

```js
testDiv.style.background = "red";
testDiv.style.removeProperty('background');
```

```css
#testDiv{
  background-color: yellow;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```